# Does mousemove event act differently according to mouse direction?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have the following piece of code

```
canvas1.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX - canvas1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var y = e.clientY - canvas1.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if (rect.currentActiveBox == currentActiveBox) {
        // Incase we try to draw another box first clear out the previous box.
        console.log('clearing ', rect);
        ctx.clearRect(rect.startX - 6 , rect.startY - 6, rect.w + 8, rect.h + 8); 
    }

    rect.startX = x;
    rect.startY = y;

    isDrawing = true;
    rect.currentActiveBox = currentActiveBox;
    rects[currentActiveBox] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rect));
});

canvas1.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(isDrawing === true) {
        // rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        // rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
        rect.w = e.pageX - rect.startX;
        rect.h = e.pageY - rect.startY;
        ctx.clearRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        rects[currentActiveBox] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rect));
    }
});
```

which just draws a box as shown below
[image]

However this only works if I drag the mouse from `top` to `bottom` manner. If I try dragging the mouse from `bottom` `up`, I get ghost boxes as shown bellow.

[image]

I would expect the `mousemove` direction shouldn't change how the drawing happens. Is there something obvious that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things:

- As ProfDFrancis has pointed out, your stroke actually extends outside the bounding box rectangle, so you need to expand your cleared area
- You're clearing the *new* rectangle rather than the previous rectangle, so if the pointer movements are more than 1px at a time you will leave artifacts
- You're being inconsistent with your pointer offsets – `pageX` and `clientX` are not interchangeable, so your commented-out calculation for `rect.w` and `rect.h` (which appears to take the element offset into consideration, as in the `mousedown` handler) is correct.

You could do something like:

```js
    if(isDrawing === true) {
        const strokeSize = 3;
        
        // Compute bounding box for all pixels touched by the stroke –
        // be sure to get a generous border to cope with antialiasing
        const clearLeft   = Math.min(rect.startX, rect.startX + rect.w) - strokeSize;
        const clearTop    = Math.min(rect.startY, rect.startY + rect.h) - strokeSize;
        const clearRight  = Math.max(rect.startX, rect.startX + rect.w) + strokeSize;
        const clearBottom = Math.max(rect.startY, rect.startY + rect.h) + strokeSize;
        ctx.clearRect(clearLeft, clearTop, clearRight - clearLeft, clearBottom - clearTop);
        
        rect.w = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - rect.startX;
        rect.h = e.pageY - this.offsetTop - rect.startY;

        ctx.beginPath();
        // etc
    }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/608aw1xr/1/)

Comment: What's amazing is that it ever worked from top-down! Javascript moves in mysterious ways, its wonders to perform. 8-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Watch out for the position of the stroke!

It is technically *outside* the rectangle that you specify in the coordinates.

Therefore, in your `mousemove` function, when you `clearRect`, you are clearing the area *inside* the red lines, and not the red lines themselves.

Further up, in your `mousedown` function, you do some good fudging to start to the left/top, and proceed wider/deeper than the nominal width/height.

Perhaps try fudging your mousemove?

For example, you could try this:

```
        ...
        rect.h = e.pageY - rect.startY;
        ctx.clearRect(rect.startX-3, rect.startY-3, rect.w+6, rect.h+6);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ...
```

If that doesn't work, try replacing the `clearRect` with a `rect` that draws a *different colour*. That way, you can check where it is trying to delete, and make sure that it is where you expect.